# Implementing facenet in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

[image]

Here I am trying to implement open face in keras.
but i am confused about that how to do triplet embedding (As Image in above link)
I know about triplet selection and convolution neural network

can someone help to figure out:

1> model structure for triplet training

2> triplet loss function

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? I am working on a project that requires a Facenet implementation in Keras, and want to know how it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The model can be anything, but generally it's a convolutional net. The triplet loss is computed on one of the late dense layer outputs, according to the formula you linked. Basically, if d(A, B) is the euclidean distance between outputs A and B (treated as vectors), then take `max(0, d(A, P)^2 - d(A, N)^2 + alpha)`